# Need help splitting the expression with regex

Tags: java, split

I have an expression like this.

```
A AND (B OR (C OR D))
```

I want the parentheses as a separate string and not combined with C OR D in the output array.

```
[A, AND, (, B, OR, (, C, OR, D, ), )]
```

Appending `,` in place of `SPACE` and after every `(` and before every `)` and then using `.split(",")` would solve my problem.

Is there any way better way to do this by simply using the right regex in the split method ?

Comment: You might want to consider an actual expression parser instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
String input = "A AND (B OR (C OR D))";
String regex = "\\s+|(?<=\\()|(?=\\))";
String[] tokens = input.split(regex);
```

Which returns:

```
{A, AND, (, B, OR, (, C, OR, D, ), )}
```

## Explanation:

The regex splits by

- One or more spaces
- Anything followed by a parenthesis
- Anything preceded by a parenthesis

I used positive lookaheads and positive lookbehinds, which are INCREDIBLY useful, so do look them up (no pun intended)

Comment: Here 'B' is split based on positive look behind of '('. Since '(' is the delimiter in case of B, it should not be in the output array right ? because that's what happens with space when it is used as a delimiter.

Comment: First the space after C is removed, so you can take  '(B' under consideration. Now the (idk what to call it) *position* between '(' and 'B' matches `(?<=\\()` , so the position counts as a division, resulting in '(' and 'B' being separated. This explanation might not have been the best, so definitely tell me if you want me to phrase it differently :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this would help:

```
"A AND (B OR (C OR D))".split(" +| (?=\\()|(?=\\))|(?<=\\()") #=> [A, AND, (, B, OR, (, C, OR, D, ), )]
```

```
 + # splits by whitespaces
 (?=\\() # splits by whitespace followed by opening brace: e.g. in " (" it would give you single "(" instead of " " and "(" (like in the next part without whitespace in the beginning)
(?=\\)) # splits by empty string followed by closing brace: e.g. "B)" => ["B", ")"]
(?<=\\)) # splits by empty string preceding by closing brace: e.g. "))"
```

Search for "Positive lookahead/lookbehind" in regular expressions (personally I use regex101.com).